# How do I add a widget to display SQLite data from data base?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

Sorry upfront for the length of this post. I tried about 10 different was to fix my issue, with no luck. I wanted to give the most context posable.

I'm new to Pyqt5. I am making a contacts app, and I am able to input data into a sqlite3 'contacts.db' file using a pyqt5 GUI app. I have the GUI input fields on the left side of the app. Where I keep getting stuck is how do I display the content of the 'contacts.db' file in a display box on the right side of the GUI app?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,  QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from sqlite3 import *  

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    # Creating Main drop window
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        # Sets dimentions for main drop window
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(1000, 425)) 

        # Sets title for main drop window    
        self.setWindowTitle("Contacts") 
        
        def firstname():

            # Creates a label for first field
            self.nameLabel1 = QLabel(self)

            # Creates label text for first label
            self.nameLabel1.setText('First Name: ')

            # Creates first field
            self.line1 = QLineEdit(self)

            # Sets placement for first field
            self.line1.move(95, 50)

            # Sets size for first field
            self.line1.resize(200, 32)

            # Sets placement for first label
            self.nameLabel1.move(20, 50)

        firstname() 

        def lastname():
            self.nameLabel2 = QLabel(self)
            self.nameLabel2.setText('Last Name: ')
            self.line2 = QLineEdit(self)
            self.line2.move(95, 100)
            self.line2.resize(200, 32)
            self.nameLabel2.move(20, 100)
        lastname()

        def email():
            self.nameLabel3 = QLabel(self)
            self.nameLabel3.setText('Email: ')
            self.line3 = QLineEdit(self)
            self.line3.move(95, 150)
            self.line3.resize(200, 32)
            self.nameLabel3.move(20, 150)
        email()

        def phone():
            self.nameLabel4 = QLabel(self)
            self.nameLabel4.setText('Phone: ')
            self.line4 = QLineEdit(self)
            self.line4.move(95, 200)
            self.line4.resize(200, 32)
            self.nameLabel4.move(20, 200)
        phone()
        
        def phone():
            self.nameLabel5 = QLabel(self)
            self.nameLabel5.setText('Location: ')
            self.line5 = QLineEdit(self)
            self.line5.move(95, 250)
            self.line5.resize(200, 32)
            self.nameLabel5.move(20, 250)
        phone()
        
        def button():

            # Creates button, and button label
            pybutton1 = QPushButton('Add Contact', self)

            # Creates framwork for button funtion
            pybutton1.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod1)

            # Sets button size
            pybutton1.resize(200,32)

            # Sets button placement
            pybutton1.move(95, 325)   
        
        button()
    # Creates action that will be preformed when first button is pressed
    def clickMethod1(self):
        conn = connect('Contacts.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        first = self.line1.text()
        last = self.line2.text()
        email = self.line3.text()
        phone = self.line4.text()
        loc = self.line5.text()

        c.execute(f"""INSERT INTO contacts VALUES('{first}',
        '{last}', '{email}', '{phone}', '{loc}')
        """)
    
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

To make the same database I have you can run this in python:

```
from sqlite3 import *

conn = connect('Contacts.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Make table
def make():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(
    first TEXT,
    last TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    phone TEXT,
    location TEXT        
    )""")
make()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt already provides support for SQL through the [QtSql](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html) module, so you usually do not need to use a separate sql module for generic usage.

Data is loaded using a *model*, and eventually displayed using a *view* (read more about the [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) paradigm of Qt.

You essentially do the following:

1. load a database engine;
2. select a database;
3. create a model (usually a [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html));
4. create a view (normally a [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html));
5. set the model for that view, using `setModel()`;

In the following example, you can see that the model is *connected* to the database, and since the modifications are done directly to the model, the table is automatically updated along with it.

<sup>Note that I reworked your code, as it had many issues: first of all, a QMainWindow should *always* have a central widget, then you should also always use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead of arbitrary sizes and positions; I also removed the functions in the `__init__` as they are unnecessary and only make the code distracting to read.</sup>

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 2)

        formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(formLayout, 0, 0)

        self.firstNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lastNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.emailEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.phoneEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.locEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        formLayout.addRow('First name:', self.firstNameEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Last name:', self.lastNameEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Email:', self.emailEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Phone:', self.phoneEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Location:', self.locEdit)

        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add contact', enabled=False)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.addButton, 1, 0)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(self.table.NoEditTriggers)

        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('Contacts.db')
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('contacts')
        self.model.select()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.mandatoryFields = self.firstNameEdit, self.lastNameEdit
        self.otherFields = self.emailEdit, self.phoneEdit, self.locEdit
        self.allFields = self.mandatoryFields + self.otherFields

        for field in self.allFields:
            field.textChanged.connect(self.validate)

        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addRecord)

    def addRecord(self):
        record = self.model.record()
        for i, field in enumerate(self.allFields):
            record.setValue(i, field.text())
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.model.setRecord(row, record)

    def validate(self):
        for field in self.mandatoryFields:
            if not field.text():
                self.addButton.setEnabled(False)
                return
        for field in self.otherFields:
            if field.text():
                break
        else:
            self.addButton.setEnabled(False)
            return
        self.addButton.setEnabled(True)
```

Also note that Qt provides a very convenient class, [QDataWidgetMapper](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html), which allows to connect *individual* widgets with fields of a model. In this way you can automatically update the fields when the user selects an index, or update the database with all fields.

Here is a slightly modified version of the code above, implementing the mapper (for simplicity I'm posting the whole code again, as the modifications are too complex):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 2)

        formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(formLayout, 0, 0)

        self.firstNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lastNameEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.emailEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.phoneEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.locEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        formLayout.addRow('First name:', self.firstNameEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Last name:', self.lastNameEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Email:', self.emailEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Phone:', self.phoneEdit)
        formLayout.addRow('Location:', self.locEdit)

        self.updateButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Update contact', enabled=False)
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add contact', enabled=False)
        buttonLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.updateButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout, 1, 0)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(self.table.NoEditTriggers)

        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('Contacts.db')
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('contacts')
        self.model.select()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(self.table.SingleSelection)

        self.mandatoryFields = self.firstNameEdit, self.lastNameEdit
        self.otherFields = self.emailEdit, self.phoneEdit, self.locEdit
        self.allFields = self.mandatoryFields + self.otherFields

        self.mapper = QtWidgets.QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(self.mapper.ManualSubmit)

        for i, field in enumerate(self.allFields):
            field.textChanged.connect(self.validate)
            self.mapper.addMapping(field, i)

        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addRecord)
        self.updateButton.clicked.connect(self.updateRecord)
        self.table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)
        self.mapper.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.validate)
        self.table.doubleClicked.connect(self.doubleClicked)
        self.table.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
            # clear all fields when clicking on an empty area of the table
            index = self.table.indexAt(event.pos())
            if not index.isValid():
                self.table.selectionModel().select(
                    index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def doubleClicked(self, index):
        widget = self.mapper.mappedWidgetAt(index.column())
        if widget:
            widget.setFocus()

    def selectedRow(self):
        selected = self.table.selectedIndexes()
        if selected:
            return selected[-1].row()
        return -1

    def selectionChanged(self):
        row = self.selectedRow()
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
        if row < 0:
            for field in self.allFields:
                field.setText('')
        self.validate()

    def addRecord(self):
        # we cannot use submit(), as it will use the *current* index, nor we can
        # insert the new row and set the new index, as it would clear all fields
        record = self.model.record()
        for i, field in enumerate(self.allFields):
            record.setValue(i, field.text())
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.model.setRecord(row, record)
        self.table.selectionModel().select(self.model.index(row, 0), 
            QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)

    def updateRecord(self):
        row = self.selectedRow()
        if row < 0:
            self.updateButton.setEnabled(False)
            return
        self.mapper.submit()

    def validate(self):
        valid = True
        for field in self.mandatoryFields:
            if not field.text():
                valid = False
                break
        else:
            for field in self.otherFields:
                if field.text():
                    break
            else:
                valid = False
        self.addButton.setEnabled(valid)
        self.updateButton.setEnabled(valid and bool(self.table.selectedIndexes()))
```